# android: google map api always starts showing from africa

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using a map fragment to show a map. But when the map starte it shows some location in africa and then shifts to the place i wanted. i have tried few solutions in the stackoverflow, which didnt work, it still starts from africa

```
CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(26.588527, 77.519531));
CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(4);
mMap.moveCamera(center);
mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
```

another solution:

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(26.588527, 77.519531), 4));
```

Comment: I believe this behaviour is default (ie. set by Google) and cannot be changed unless you only show the map after the map has shifted to your location.

Comment: ok. then its fine. any reference

Comment: What are magic numbers 26.588527,77.519531?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure [initial map state](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#configure_initial_state):

using `cameraTargetLat`, `cameraTargetLng`, `cameraZoom` XML attributes, e.g.:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraTargetLat="26.588527"
    map:cameraTargetLng="77.519531"
    map:cameraZoom="4"/>
```

programmatically using [GoogleMapOptions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions), e.g.:

```
CameraPosition indiaPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(new LatLng(26.588527, 77.519531))
    .zoom(4)
    .build();

GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions().camera(camera)

SupportMapFragment map = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(mapOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//setting India region in google maps
LatLngBounds INDIA = new LatLngBounds(
        new LatLng(7.2, 67.8), new LatLng(36.5, 93.8));

map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(INDIA.getCenter(), 5));
```

this would set India region on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(26.588527, 77.519531), 11.5f), 4500, null);
```

works very well !!